# Material Design Web 1.0 quickstart problem with script module and onclick handler

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I am trying to get a jumpstart with [Material Design Web](https://material.io/develop/web/) 1.0 from March 2019.

But I have a problem at the beginning:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; script-src 'unsafe-inline' https://unpkg.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https://unpkg.com https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Test</title>

        <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
    
        <script type="module">
          const menu = mdc.menu.MDCMenu.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-menu'));
          menu.open = false;
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header class="mdc-top-app-bar mdc-top-app-bar--fixed mdc-menu-surface--anchor">
          <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
            <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
              <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon" onclick="menu.open = !menu.open;">menu</a>
              <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Test</span>
            </section>
            <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-end" role="toolbar">
            </section>
          </div>
          <div class="mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface" tabindex="-1">
            <ul class="mdc-list" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-orientation="vertical">
              <li class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem"><span class="mdc-list-item__text">Homepage</span></li>
              <li class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem"><span class="mdc-list-item__text">Imprint</span></li>
              <li class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem"><span class="mdc-list-item__text">Data privacy statement</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>

      </body>
    </html>
```

My problem ist, that for the `onclick="menu.open = !menu.open;"` the browsers console tolds me that it is undefined. Thats because of the `<script type="module">`. But when removing the `type="module"` then the content of the script tag throws an error that there is something undefined.

So my question is:

Whats the correct way (when using the quickstart with unpkg.com - see [Getting Started](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/)) to open/close a menu within an onclick handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the `variable`'s scope issue. In the `type='module'` variables don't automatically get declared globally like normal `script`. You have to attach them to the `window` object manually.
Below both options can resolve your issue.

[manually attached to the window](https://jsfiddle.net/fvg0eht5/)

```
    <script type="module">
          window.menu = mdc.menu.MDCMenu.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-menu'));
          window.menu.open = false; 
          window.toggleMenu = function () { window.menu.open = !window.menu.open }
    </script>

    <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon" id="button" onclick="toggleMenu();">menu</a>
```

Second Option: instead of `onclick`, use `addEventListener`

[by adding Event Listener](https://jsfiddle.net/8wLfq3nt/2/)

```
<script type="module">    
  const menu = mdc.menu.MDCMenu.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-menu')); 
        menu.open = false;
  document.getElementById('toggleButton').addEventListener('click', () => menu.open = !menu.open);
</script>
```

hope helps you...